# Cron expression for biweekly scheduler job on Monday in Windows 10 using Java

Tags: java, windows, cron, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

I have created a scheduler with two triggers to implement a biweekly scheduler Java program on Windows 10 using Cron expression. The two jobs are **executed individually one each on alternate Monday of every month** at 2pm, so maybe on even alternates or odd alternates. The **current Cron expressions** in use are as follows -

```
"0 0 14 ? * MON#1"
"0 0 14 ? * MON#3"
```

I want to implement both these jobs with a single trigger and thus a **single Cron expression**, but **not able to club these two Cron expressions**. Need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quartz cron triggers do not support multiple "Nth" days.

However, if you do not mind, you can use a CalendarIntervalTrigger that is more suitable for this type of a schedule. The following screenshot (from [QuartzDesk](https://quartzdesk.com) GUI) shows you a CalendarIntervalTrigger with settings that cover your use-case.

[image: Biweekly CalendarIntervalTrigger Example]

Comment: Thanks, yes it makes sense!